# Equivalent of a composite index across multiple tables?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table structure similar the following:

```
create table MAIL (
  ID        int,
  FROM      varchar,
  SENT_DATE date
);

create table MAIL_TO (
  ID      int,
  MAIL_ID int,
  NAME      varchar
);
```

and I need to run the following query:

```
select m.ID 
from MAIL m 
  inner join MAIL_TO t on t.MAIL_ID = m.ID
where m.SENT_DATE between '07/01/2010' and '07/30/2010'
  and t.NAME = 'someone@example.com'
```

Is there any way to design indexes such that both of the conditions can use an index? If I put an index on MAIL.SENT_DATE and an index on MAIL_TO.NAME, the database will choose to use either one of the indexes or the other, not both. After filtering by the first condition the database always has to do a full scan of the results for the second condition.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't do a #TempTable and index that on those two columns?

Comment: @JNK: I see your indexed temp table, and raise you a materialized view...

Comment: @OMG Ponies - +1, you're the expert I just hang out here and chime in from time to time :)  Also I'm not exactly super familiar with Oracle, mainly use SQL Server 2008.

Comment: @JNK: I'm no expert - I wait for peeps like APC, Gary, Mr. Kemp, Tony Andrew, Rob... and others I forget to learn me on the finer details of Oracle.

Comment: No particular reason. This is an existing database/application and it's running a bit on the slow side. The sample query is representative of most of the queries that are run. I was hoping to be able to speed it up a bit by just adjusting the indexes.

Comment: Why is this question being voted down?

Comment: @tpdi - my fault - by mistake I clicked on the down vote and didn't notice it until too much time had passed to roll back the vote.  My apologies to jthg - it's a good question and I'm glad someone offset my mistake with an upvote.  I looked on meta and found that the time limit on rollback prevents some specific gaming of the vote system.

Comment: Maybe this will help someone..https://blogs.oracle.com/searchtech/indexing-data-from-multiple-tables-with-oracle-text

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [materialized view](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96567/repmview.htm) would allow you to index the values, assuming the stringent materialized view criteria is met.

Comment: I assume that the application will need to be modified to refer to the materialized view instead?

Comment: @jthg: Yes, it's a view - just faster/more efficient than an ordinary view.

Answer (score 7):

Oracle can use both indices. You just don't have the *right* two indices.

Consider: if the query plan uses your index on `mail.sent_date` first, what does it get from `mail`? It gets all the `mail.id`s where `mail.sent_date` is within the range you gave in your `where` clause, yes?

So it goes to `mail_to` with a list of `mail.id`s and the `mail.name` you gave in your `where` clause. At this point, Oracle decides that it's better to scan the table for matching `mail_to.mail_id`s rather than use the index on `mail_to.name`.

Indices on varchars are always problematic, and Oracle really prefers full table scans. But if we give Oracle an index containing the columns it really *wants* to use, and depending on total table rows and statistics, we can get it to use it. This is the index:

```
 create index mail_to_pid_name on mail_to( mail_id, name ) ;
```

This works where an index just on `name` doesn't, because Oracle's not looking just for a name, but for a `mail_id` *and* a `name`.

Conversely, if the cost-based analyzer determines it's cheaper to go to table `mail_to` first, and uses your index on `mail_to.name`, what doe sit get? A bunch of `mail_to_.mail_id`s to look up in `mail`. It needs to find rows with those ids *and* certain sent_dates, so:

```
 create index mail_id_sentdate on mail( sent_date, id ) ;
```

Note that in this case I've put `sent_date` first in the index, and `id` second. (This is more an intuitive thing.)

Again, the take home point is this: in creating indices, you have to consider not just the columns in your `where` clause, but also the columns in your join conditions.

---

Update

jthg: yes, it always depends on how the data is distributed. And on how many rows are in the table: if very many, Oracle will do a  table scan and hash join, if very few it will do a table scan. You might reverse the order of either of the two indices. By putting sent_date first in the second index, we eliminate most needs for an index solely on `sent_date`.

Comment: Thanks, but wouldn't the two indexes that you suggested be not very helpful? The first index would still force the database to try every MAIL_ID within the sent_date range, it just saves the time of scanning the few MAIL_TO's associated with each MAIL. The second index is no different from an index on just sent_date since no two sent_dates are going to be exactly the same.

Comment: @jthg: Oracle, as most modern engines, can make use of columns in an index and not in a table by avoiding to access the table at all:
If it scans an index and finds rowIds, and then has to go back to the disk to fetch the table pages containing these rowIds, that is a lot of effort, especially if the pages are widely spread on the disk. If the second column searched is part of the index, this additional disk access is avoided. Add to that the smaller record size of indexes (normally much fewer columns), and hence the data is spread over less pages, and hence there is less I/O this way.

Comment: I see what you mean. The optimizations you suggested should provide a constant factor speed up in the queries - which is definitely useful in many situations. I was hoping for an improvement in the big O performance of the queries though and I think OMG Ponies suggestion of using a materialized view would provide that.

Answer (score 1):

In situations where the requirements aren't met for a materialized view, there are these two options:

1) You can create a cross reference table, and keep this updated with triggers.

The concepts would be the same with Oracle, but i only have SQL Server installed at the moment to run the test, see this setup:

```
create table MAIL (
  ID        INT IDENTITY(1,1),
  [FROM]      VARCHAR(200),
  SENT_DATE DATE,
  CONSTRAINT PK_MAIL PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

create table MAIL_TO (
  ID      INT IDENTITY(1,1),
  MAIL_ID INT,
  [NAME]     VARCHAR (200),
  CONSTRAINT PK_MAIL_TO PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MAIL_TO]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_MAILTO_MAIL] FOREIGN KEY([MAIL_ID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[MAIL] ([ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MAIL_TO] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_MAILTO_MAIL]
GO


CREATE TABLE CompositeIndex_MailSentDate_MailToName ( 
[MAIL_ID] INT,
[MAILTO_ID] INT,
SENT_DATE DATE,
MAILTO_NAME VARCHAR(200),
CONSTRAINT PK_CompositeIndex_MailSentDate_MailToName PRIMARY KEY (MAILTO_ID,MAIL_ID)
)

GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_MailSent_MailTo ON dbo.CompositeIndex_MailSentDate_MailToName (SENT_DATE,MAILTO_NAME)
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_MailTo_MailSent ON dbo.CompositeIndex_MailSentDate_MailToName (MAILTO_NAME,SENT_DATE)
GO

CREATE TRIGGER dbo.trg_MAILTO_Insert
ON dbo.MAIL_TO  
AFTER INSERT AS  
BEGIN 
 INSERT INTO dbo.CompositeIndex_MailSentDate_MailToName ( MAIL_ID, MAILTO_ID, SENT_DATE, MAILTO_NAME )
 SELECT mailTo.MAIL_ID,mailTo.ID,m.SENT_DATE,mailTo.NAME
 FROM
 inserted mailTo
 INNER JOIN dbo.MAIL m ON m.ID = mailTo.MAIL_ID
END
GO


CREATE TRIGGER dbo.trg_MAILTO_Delete
ON dbo.MAIL_TO  
AFTER DELETE AS  
BEGIN 
 DELETE mailToDelete
 FROM
 dbo.MAIL_TO mailToDelete
 INNER JOIN deleted ON mailToDelete.ID = deleted.ID
END
GO

CREATE TRIGGER dbo.trg_MAILTO_Update
ON dbo.MAIL_TO  
AFTER UPDATE AS  
BEGIN 
 UPDATE compositeIndex
 SET
 compositeIndex.MAILTO_NAME = updates.NAME
 FROM
 dbo.CompositeIndex_MailSentDate_MailToName compositeIndex
 INNER JOIN inserted updates ON updates.ID = compositeIndex.MAILTO_ID
END
GO

CREATE TRIGGER dbo.trg_MAIL_Update
ON dbo.MAIL  
AFTER UPDATE AS  
BEGIN 
 UPDATE compositeIndex
 SET
 compositeIndex.SENT_DATE = updates.SENT_DATE
 FROM
 dbo.CompositeIndex_MailSentDate_MailToName compositeIndex
 INNER JOIN inserted updates ON updates.ID = compositeIndex.MAIL_ID
END
GO


INSERT INTO dbo.MAIL ( [FROM], SENT_DATE )
SELECT 'SenderA','2018-10-01'
UNION ALL SELECT 'SenderA','2018-10-02'

INSERT INTO dbo.MAIL_TO ( MAIL_ID, NAME )
SELECT 1,'CustomerA'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,'CustomerB'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,'CustomerC'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,'CustomerD'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,'CustomerE'


SELECT * FROM dbo.MAIL
SELECT * FROM dbo.MAIL_TO
SELECT * FROM dbo.CompositeIndex_MailSentDate_MailToName
```

You can then use the `dbo.CompositeIndex_MailSentDate_MailToName` table to JOIN to the rest of your data. This is useful in environments where your rate of inserts and updates are low, but your query needs are high. So the relative overhead of implementing the triggers is small.

This has the advantage of being updated transactionally, in real time.

2) If you don't want the performance/management overhead of a trigger, and you only need this for next day reporting, you can create a view, and a nightly process which truncates the table and selects the entire view into a materialized table.

I've used this successfully to index flattened relational data requiring joins across a dozen or so tables.. reducing report times from hours to seconds. While it's an expensive query, you can set the job to run off hours if you have periods of reduced usage.

Answer (score 0):

Which criterion is more selective? The date range or the addressee? I would guess the addressee. And if that is highly selective, do not care for the date index, just let the database do the search based on the found mail ids. But index table `MAIL` on the id if it is not already.

On the other hand, some modern optimizers would even make use of both indexes, scanning both tables and than build a hash value of the join columns to merge the results of both. I am not absolutely sure if and when Oracle would chose this strategy. I just realized that SQL Server tends to make hash joins rather often, compared to other engines.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I can't see though how doing a hash join would make the select faster. It will still need to do a full scan of the results from each condition.

Comment: I was assuming the optimizer would use both indexes to restrict the two inputs to the hash join. Of course, records with the correct addressee and the wrong date and vice versa would still be in the inputs of these, but not any records for other addressees from MAIL_TO or out of date range from MAIL.

Answer (score 0):

If your queries are generally for a particular month, then you could [partition](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/datawarehouse-bigdata/partitioning.html) the data by month.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not the case. The range is arbitrary.